# I want to know how we can send email to selected contacts.. and the contacts will be selected from visualsorce page

Tags: email

```
public class EmailSendController{
    public List<contact> contacts{get;set;}
    public List<ModelClass> models{get;set;}
    public list <contact> con1{get;set;}
    public ModelClass model{get;set;}
    public EmailSendController()
    {
        contacts = new List<contact>();
        con1 = new List<contact>();
        models = new List<ModelClass>();

        contacts = [select id,firstname,lastname from contact];


        for(contact obj:contacts)
        {
            model = new ModelClass();
            model.std = obj ;
            model.flag = false;
            models.add(model);

        }
        model = new ModelClass();
    }

     public void show(){

        if(model.flag == true)
        {
            model.flag = false;
        }
        else
        {
            model.flag = true;
        }


    }

    public void save()
    {

           for(ModelClass con:models){
                if(con.flag == true)
                {
                    con1.add(con.std);
                    con.flag = false;
                } 
            }


            for(Contact obj:con1)
            {
                EmailTemplate template=[select id from EmailTemplate where developername = 'Groupemail'];
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                String[] ToAddresses = new String[] {'anamika@gmail.com'}; 
                mail.setToAddresses(ToAddresses);
                mail.setTemplateId(template.id);

                mail.setTargetObjectId(obj.id);
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                mail.setToAddresses(ToAddresses);
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

            }

    }


     public class ModelClass{
        public contact std{get;set;}
        public Boolean flag{get;set;}

    } 


}
```

==========================================
//page

```
<apex:page controller="EmailSendController">
  <apex:form id="frm">

      <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
              <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!models}" var="m">
                <apex:column >
                <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!m.flag}"> 
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!show}"/>
                </apex:inputcheckbox>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="First Name">

                    <apex:outputField value="{!m.std.firstname}"/>
                </apex:column>
                 <apex:column headerValue="Phone">

                    <apex:outputField value="{!m.std.lastname}"/>
                </apex:column>

              </apex:pageBlockTable>         
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
              <apex:pageblockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            </apex:pageblockButtons>

      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any error handling - you should look at the return value of Messaging.sendEmail and also use Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity - the code to send the emails would look like this:

```
public PageReference send() {
    EmailTemplate template = [
            select Id
            from EmailTemplate
            where developername = 'Groupemail'
            ];
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {};
    for (ModelClass m : models) {
        if (m.flag) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            message.setTargetObjectId(m.std.Id);
            message.setTemplateId(template.Id);
            messages.add(message);
        }
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(messages, true /* allOrNothing */));
    return null;
}
```

You do not need to have the apex:actionSupport in your page; using an apex:commandButton ensures that the selections are updated in the controller.

The controller class just needs to be this (note the check that the Contact.Email address is set on the Contacts shown;  if not set Messaging.sendEmail will complain):

```
public class EmailSendController {

    public class ModelClass {
        public contact std {get;set;}
        public Boolean flag {get;set;}
        ModelClass(contact std) {
            this.std = std;
            this.flag = true;
        }
    } 

    public List<ModelClass> models {get;set;}

    public EmailSendController() {
        models = new List<ModelClass>();
        for (Contact c : [
                select id,firstname,lastname
                from contact
                where email != null
                order by name
                limit 1000
                ]) {
            models.add(new ModelClass(c));
        }
    }

    public PageReference send() {
        // As above
    }
}
```